# R read a txt file write specific column to new txt file

Tags: r, loops

I need to read a file "001.txt" with 3 columns, and export a file with a new name "new001C2.txt" that only contains the second column. I can do this sort of thing one file at a time, but I'm just starting out and haven't been able to find an automated way to do this for all the files in the directory.

Comment: Share your code to do it with one file, and we can help you turn it into a function and apply it to all files in a directory.

Comment: Thanks shujaa. Here is what I can do with one file:  X <- read.csv("001.txt", header=TRUE);   X2<- X[,2];   write(X2, file= "new001C2.txt", ncolumns =1, sep="")

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `lapply`.  First, make a list of all the file names.  Then read them all with `lapply`.  This puts each file into a list, so "001.txt" will be the first member of the list, and can be accessed with `readAll[[1]]`.  `newFiles` creates a list of new files, keeping the numbers in line with the original file names.  Then we use `lapply` again to write each to a separate file.

```
files <- c("001.txt", "002.txt", "003.txt")

readAll <- lapply(files, read.csv) 

col2 <- lapply(readAll, function(x) x[,2])

newFiles <- paste0("new", gsub(".txt", "", files), "C2.txt")

lapply(1:length(col2), function(i) write(col2[[i]], newFiles[i]))
```

Comment: Thanks RScriv. I'm not sure why it's not working: Error in lapply(files, read.csv)[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Sorry about that.  I think it's fixed now.

Comment: thanks RScriv. One final issue. The new name has to retain the number from the old file name, and unfortunately these are subject ids with gaps between numbers. So for example, if the first subject is 005.txt, he's 1st on the list, so his new file is new001C2 instead of new005C2. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That should be fine so long as the names in the `files` list are "005.txt", etc.  The file names are not used, but they are indexed.  `1:length(files)` is (in this case) 1 to 3.  So the new file names should be "new001C2.txt", "new002C2.txt", "new003C2.txt"

Comment: I understand. So I will basically have to match up new001 with 005, new002 with 028, etc. I can do that, but if there's a simple way of using the old file name in the new file name it would be great, I have hundreds of subjects.

Comment: I added `gsub` to the last line of code, so not the original file names (should) match the "new" ones.

Comment: Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (substring(file, 1L,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (substring(file, 1L, 1L) == "|") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a linux based system, here's a simpler solution you can run directly from the shell:

```
cut -f 2 001.txt > new001C2.txt
```